# Dofollow links disabled using url requests in python

Tags: javascript, python, url, request

I built a light weight web scraping program to parse through a user's profile on ResearchGate. Previously when I was utilizing the following code I could discover and visit href links but now after executing the program few times I am only receiving one href mentioning that enable javascript to dofollow.

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

main_url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luqun_Li3'
url =  main_url + '/research'
page = requests.get(url)

bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')

pub_links = []
for link in bs.findAll('a'):
    print(link)
    if 'publication/' in link.get('href'):
        pub_links.append(link.get('href'))
        print('found link')
        visiting_links = remove_dupes(pub_links)
```

Previously when I executed the afoemrntioend code I would be able to view and discover links which were starting with 'publication/' but now there's only one link available saying:

'a  href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank"> instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser a

Can someone help me to enable javascript for dofollow links so that I can keep using this program for parsing?